# Java Jpanel, can't set background color

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a main class that extends a JFrame, which then adds a jpanel to the jframe. Then I try to set the background color of the jpanel, but to no avail. I'm not really sure where the problem is, according to what i've found on google, simply setting `setBackground(Color)` in the JPanel should fix this but it doesn't seem to work. Also other fixes for this were `setOpaque(true)`, and `setVisible(true)`, or form the JFrame using `getContentPane().setBackground(Color)` But none of these seem to work. Any suggestions would be very appreciated, and if you need more info, or have other advice, please feel free to enlighten me. :)
The main class is:

```
public class main extends JFrame{

    private Content content;

    public main(){

        content = new Content(400, 600);

        this.setTitle("Shooter2.0");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.getContentPane().add(content);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        main game = new main();
    }

}
```

and the Content class is:

```
public class Content extends JPanel{

    private viewItem ship;

    public Content(int w, int h){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());     
        this.createBattlefield();
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.repaint();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createBattlefield(){
        ship = new viewItem("bubble-field.png", 180, 550, 40, 42);      
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        ship.draw(g);       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overriding `paint` without calling

```
super.paint(g);
```

This prevents the background and child components from being painted.

For custom painting in Swing override `paintComponent` *instead* and take advantage of Swing's optimized paint model, annotate with `@Override` and invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`.

[Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: `paintComponent` uses double buffering so is more performant.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace** the code block

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    ship.draw(g);       
}
```

**By**

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);        
    ship.draw(g);       
}
```

you are setting the background color of JPanel in constructor so there is no need it in paintComponent(){} method...

**try above code it will surely works....**